# XSLT For Namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, replace, namespaces

I know there are a lot of posts about using XSLT 1.0 to change namespaces but I haven't gotten any of them to work. Perhaps it's the processor I'm using?

I've tried both http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html and http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php to test out my XSLT.

Anyhow, I have this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:GetActiveSuppliersResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservice">
         <GetActiveSuppliersReturn soapenc:arrayType="ns2:asl.webservice.SupplierDTO[3]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:ns2="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <GetActiveSuppliersReturn href="#id0"/>
            <GetActiveSuppliersReturn href="#id1"/>
            <GetActiveSuppliersReturn href="#id2"/>
         </GetActiveSuppliersReturn>
      </ns1:GetActiveSuppliersResponse>
      <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:asl.webservice.SupplierDTO" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns3="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion">
         <asl_status xsi:type="xsd:string">Archived</asl_status>
         <zip xsi:type="xsd:string">11735</zip>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:asl.webservice.SupplierDTO" xmlns:ns4="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <asl_status xsi:type="xsd:string">Archived</asl_status>
         <zip xsi:type="xsd:string">92880</zip>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns5:asl.webservice.SupplierDTO" xmlns:ns5="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <asl_status xsi:type="xsd:string">Archived</asl_status>
         <zip xsi:type="xsd:string">91355</zip>
      </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to change all namespaces of `http://rpc.xml.coldfusion` to `http://DefaultNamespace` and all instances of `asl.webservice.SupplierDTO` to `webservice.supplierdto`, including the arrayType.

So I would like the resulting XML to look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:GetActiveSuppliersResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservice">
         <GetActiveSuppliersReturn soapenc:arrayType="ns2:webservice.supplierdto[3]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:ns2="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <GetActiveSuppliersReturn href="#id0"/>
            <GetActiveSuppliersReturn href="#id1"/>
            <GetActiveSuppliersReturn href="#id2"/>
         </GetActiveSuppliersReturn>
      </ns1:GetActiveSuppliersResponse>
      <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:webservice.supplierdto" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns3="http://DefaultNamespace">
         <asl_status xsi:type="xsd:string">Archived</asl_status>
         <zip xsi:type="xsd:string">11735</zip>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:webservice.supplierdto" xmlns:ns4="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <asl_status xsi:type="xsd:string">Archived</asl_status>
         <zip xsi:type="xsd:string">92880</zip>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns5:webservice.supplierdto" xmlns:ns5="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <asl_status xsi:type="xsd:string">Archived</asl_status>
         <zip xsi:type="xsd:string">91355</zip>
      </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone help me come up with an XSLT that will do the transformation mentioned above?

Comment: There is no `asl.webservice.SupplierDTO`  namespace in your XML. It looks like you are asking two unrelated questions at the same time. -- Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Michael, thanks for the reply. I didn't say it was a namespace, I said I'd like to replace all instances of asl.webservice,SupplierDTO. Unfortunately I can't use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Well, you should ask that as a separate question. -- The other thing is this: there are no nodes in the `http://rpc.xml.coldfusion` namespace in your XML. Although there are 4 namespace declaration binding this namespace to various prefixes, none of these prefixes are actually used. You will have a hard time changing those redundant declarations in XSLT 1.0 - and changing them would serve no purpose anyway.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did notice that the prefixes weren't being used. The payload in my post is the response from a web service I'm consuming. The service I'm consuming was upgraded and it changed the response a little bit as shown above. I'd like to translate the response to what it was, as it is breaking now. So you know of no XSLT that would modify the XML as requested?

Comment: I know of no easy way to do so in XSLT 1.0. And I am not going to suggest a hard way because I don't find the problem sufficiently interesting to spend *that* amount of time on it. --  "*I'd like to translate the response to what it was, as it is breaking now.*" Can you identify what exactly is breaking your consuming application? A well-behaved XML parser should ignore those redundant namespace declarations. Perhaps there is another - simpler - schema you can transform the original XML into, that your target application can read - even if its XML parser is not well-behaved .